# UICollectionView does not reveal all cells in Simulator

Tags: uicollectionview, uinavigationitem, uicollectionviewlayout, vertical-scrolling

I am not very experienced with UICollectionView and Auto-Layout.

I have a very basic UICollectionView inside a root view. The root view seems to have a Navigation Item.

I created a custom cell which is really a square in proper size to allow 2 such cells per row using the FlowLayout.

There are 8 such cells in the view - it is basically a grid. I have absolutely no constraints on the view.

The collection view occupies the entire size of the root view according to the IB and in the editor, the first cell is placed right under the navigation item which is perfect.

However, when I ran the app in the simulator and scrolled the collectionview all the way to the button, I see only a partial fragment of both cells in the last row. I can see I have scrolled all the way down...

Obviously there seems to be some sort of overflow...but I would have thought uicollectionview would automatically handle the overflow and make all the cells visible?

When I set number of items in IB I can see that the cells in the last row are only partially visible.

Seems like content size of the collection view is not right - that's my guess..

What do I need to do to adjust things in IB so that all of my cells are visible...I do not want to hardcode any values in the code...

Thanks.

Comment: turns out simulator does not show the entire collection view...the same shows fine on the device...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turns out simulator does not show the entire collection view...the same shows fine on the device... What a headache...